# Training Plan for High School 3-5km cross-country Run

Tags: running

I've started to see the potential that I have in running after I came third in Division cross country with only 1 week of training beforehand and having no previous sport experience. I want to start training and see where that takes me and I know others will too!

I'm looking for a good spread out training plan with a span of around 10-30 weeks (with both running [not on all days] and weight training). My personal best for the 1.6km/1mile run is 5:34 and I want to make it to the 3km cross country U15 boys state team.

I am quite fit and am able to run all days except Tuesday. If any coaches or experienced runners have a good, hard training plan/program that I can use, please feel free to post it down below.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm a former DII collegiate runner and NASM-CES certified trainer with 4-5 yrs individual coaching experience. My recommendation is to read Daniels Running Formula by Jack Daniels. It includes written out plans in the book and explains everything. This makes it easier to understand what and why you're doing everything and I've used his philosophy and style for training successfully with myself and clients.

Comment: @CodyParks Post that as an answer and gather the sweet upvotes.

Comment: Thanks Cody, I'll have a look and as Dave said, post it as an answer!

Comment: Daniels is a good read. I'll dig up the program I wrote for my cousin (Colorado 5A x-country) and post that as another reference for you.

Comment: I agree Daniels would be a good place to start.  Although, it may be worth joining an athletic club,  so you can get some coaching, and be pushed on by other athletes

Comment: Thomas, can you let us know your current mileage load and speed work, along with how long you have been doing this training?  In my high school, runners did only 20-30 miles per week and a few were able to run sub 4:30 miles and sub 17 minute 5Ks.

Answer (score 1):

I got an app called mapmyrun which allows you to create a 5K plan with the amount of workouts you want, and days for long runs. Also it can track your runs and help you see where you can improve and so. I've been using it and from being a couch potato I can now actually run.

Answer (score -1):

Start here: http://www.halhigdon.com/training/50934/5K-Intermediate-Training-Program

Do strength training 2-3 times per week. As you get closer to your key race (2-3 weeks), reduce the amount of strength training to 0-1 times per week.

Comment: It's best to post the actual answer as the links can become stale and then an accepted answer really doesn't do any good to the next person.